# The window close right after terminal terminating

Tags: c, x11

I created the X window:

```
Win = XCreateSimpleWindow(Dsp, DefaultRootWindow(Dsp), 0, 0, 600, 600, 0, 0, 0);
```

, and then this window would close right after terminal terminating.

How to make a window that won't close if terminal terminate? Change its father window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nohup is a POSIX command to ignore the HUP (hangup) signal.

```
nohup program &
```

Or you can do this programatically using `signal`s:

```
signal(SIGHUP, catcher); /* dont die on sighup */
```